# Hightlight color for NSDatepickerCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to do a little timer app in Objective-C/Cocoa. I am using the NSDatePicker to be able to set the start value. I managed to change the text color to green, because the whole app will be in green on a HUD panel:

[date picker right http://jeenaparadies.net/t/s/datepicker-right.png](http://jeenaparadies.net/t/s/datepicker-right.png)

But there is a problem. Whenever I am using the picker to change the value, it highlights it wit a gray color and you can't se what value it has unless you click somewhere else:

[date picker wrong http://jeenaparadies.net/t/s/datepicker-wrong.png](http://jeenaparadies.net/t/s/datepicker-wrong.png)

I am looking for hours now, but have no clue how to fix it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDatePickerCell is a subclass of NSCell, which has the -highlightColorWithFrame:inView: method, which you can override and return any highlight color you wish.

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain how to override the method and return any desired color?

Comment: It works the same way as it does with any Objective-C class. See this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858457/objective-c-overriding-method-in-subclass