# Method defined in both class and inherited class

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

In objective-c, if a method is defined in both class and inherited class of that class, and I call that method from a different class, how will my compiler know which method to pick? The original method in the parent class or the override method in the inherited class. In my code I am calling the method name through my parent class, but compiler is picking up method in the inherited class.

Example:

Lets say I have a parent class `Super` and a sub class `Sub`. Both of them implement method `Match`. Now in another class, say `OtherClass`, I define

```
Super *super = [[Super alloc]init];
```

and I call method `Match` in `OtherClass`

```
[super Match]
```

Will `Match` in `Super` be called or `Match` in `Sub` be called?

Comment: Are you satisfied with one of the answers? Are you sure you have the same method signatures in both classes?

Comment: Yes. I have the same method signatures in both classes. The issue is what I have mentioned in my edited question because no where at all I am using my subclass object to call my method, instead I am using my superclass object and the method being called is the sub class one. If you can shed some light on why this happens, it would be great.

Comment: Here `[[Super alloc]init]`you are creating Super object. So `Match` in `Super` will be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective C all instance methods are "virtual" in terms of C++ for example.

For example if you have 2 classes

```
@interface A
- (void)doSomething;
@end;

@interface B : A
- (void)doSomething;
- (void)doSomethingB;
@end;
```

And you will call

```
A *a = [A new];
B *b = [B new];

[(B*)a doSomething]; // method from A is called
[(A*)b doSomething]; // method from B is called

[a doSomethingB]; // compile error. No such method for A
[(A*)b doSomethingB]; // compile error. No such method for A
[(B*)a doSomethingB]; // compiles, but runtime exception. Undefined method for A
```

The compiler will always call the method of the inherited class in your case.

Answer (score 2):

It will call the method for whatever class the object is. You obviously have an instance of the subclass, so you get the sub class's implementation.

You probably are using a variable with the superclass type, but that doesn't matter — the type of the variable is just for static type checking. Method dispatch is done based on the class of the object itself. And variables are allowed to refer to subclasses of their declared type, so the type checker won't flag that as an error.

Comment: I am using the object from my SuperClass.  I donot fully understand the explanation you gave in the answer. I have added some details in my question to make my confusion little clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the core behavior of `Inheritance` and `Polymorphism`. The compiler will always pick up the method in the `inherited` class. By this way, you can acquire the behavior `polymorphism`. Using the concepts of `polymorphism`, you can design a class efficiently that complies with the standard of Class Design principles such as [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principle.

Comment: So what if I have two inherited classes and both are overriding the same method in parent class? How will compiler figure out which method to call then?

Comment: It's not quite accurate to say it will "always pick up the method of the inherited class." It will pick up the method of the class of the object the message is sent to. That could be the subclass or it could be the superclass.

Comment: @azmuhak you will have an instance of the base class to which you will assign the instance of the derived classes which you want. So, after assigning, you can invoke the method through the instance of base class, but the method of the derived class instance that you assigned to it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858457/objective-c-overriding-method-in-subclass) you can see that how it will behave. This topic is discussed earlier on SO

You will have to explicitly mention if you want to call same method from super class otherwise it will be called from the child or subclass.

Answer (score -1):

It will always call the method in the inherited class. If class A is the base class, and B is the inherited class, tehn

```
B *objB = [[B alloc] init];
A *objA = (objA *)B;
[objA someMethod];
```

Even if objA is of type A, it is pointing to an object of class B. Therefore someMethod will be called on the implementation of B.

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk: I'm not the downvoter, but the statement "It will always call the method in the inherited class" is a bit overbroad. That's probably why.

Comment: @Chuck But accordingly to question it is the most straight answer. Besides, it will  always begin look for method selector from inherited class, no?

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk: Not always, no. If you send a message to an instance of the superclass, it will not look in the subclass for the method.

Comment: @Chuck sure,  right. But I meant that if call method of subclass, like in Merlevede's example. I had read question again and have to agree that answer is really unclear, especialy if not familiar with inheritance mechanism. Thanks for explanations)