# How can i make a custon NSDatePickerCell for change the select color?

Tags: swift, macos, datepicker

I need to make a custom `NSDatePickerCell` to custom the highlight Color of this.

Also i read another question here: [Hightlight color for NSDatepickerCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910048/hightlight-color-for-nsdatepickercell)

And I override the method:

```
override func highlightColor(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) -> NSColor? {
        return NSColor.green
}
```

This method never is called.

Another method is this:

```
override func highlight(_ flag: Bool, withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
    NSColor.green.set()
    cellFrame.fill()
}
```

But if i set a color on this method for the cell frame, the program crash by :

> CGContext invalid

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done by overriding `NSDatePickerCell`. It doesn't use `highlightColor`, it uses the system accent color which is set by the user in System Preferences.

Probably the only way to change the selection color is to subclass `NSControl` and make your own picker.